# How to fetch data from list of dict?

Tags: python

I trying to gather the data if the b_name exits, if so, fetch b_ip into the list.

Data:

```
data = {'A-01': [[{'a': '192.168.1.1',
                'b': '192.168.1.0'},
               {'a': '192.168.1.3',
                'b': '192.168.1.2'}],
              [{'a': '192.168.2.19',
                'b': '192.168.2.18',
                'b_name': 'CC0-01'}]],
     'B-02': [[{'a': '192.168.2.83',
                'b': '192.168.2.82',
                'b_name': 'CC0-02'},
               {'a': '192.168.2.85',
                'b': '192.168.2.84',
                'b_name': 'CC0-02'}]]}
```

Code I have tried:

```
iplist = []
for key, value in data.items():
        for i in value:
            if type(i) is dict:
                if 'b_name' in i and 'CC0' in i['b_name']:
                    iplist.append(i['b'])
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Have you done any debugging? Why are you doing `if type(i) is dict:`, isn't the format of the data consistent? As an aside, don't use `in` for equality, use `==` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra level of lists that you're not iterating over.

```
iplist = []
for value in data.values():
    for i in value:
        for j in i:
            if type(j) is dict:
                if 'b_name' in j and 'CC0' in j['b_name']:
                    iplist.append(j['b'])
```

Comment: thanks @barmar, I added one check `if not j['b'] in iplist, and also replace last check from `i` to `j`. which is works now.. thanks

Comment: You could use a `set` instead of a `list` if you want to prevent duplicates.

Comment: how to break into different list, based on the different keys. for example:
```
`A-01`: ['192.168.2.18']
`'B-02': ['192.168.2.82', '192.168.2.84'] ```

Comment: `ip_dict[key].append(j['b'])`

Comment: to get the key, I should another layer for the keys? so before:
`for key in data.keys():`

Comment: `for key, value in data.items():` like in your original script. I removed that in my version because the keys weren't being used.

Comment: `defaultdict` may also be useful to initialize the new elements.

Comment: yes, I used defaultdict, thanks `ip_dict.setdefault(key,[]).append(j['b'])`